# How can I enable libmongoc ssl in PHP 7 for Mongodb connection?

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, http

While connecting to mongodb via PHP7, I am getting following error:

> The "SCRAM-SHA-1" authentication mechanism requires libmongoc built
>   with --enable-ssl

This is probably due to libmongoc SSL disabled in php7:

```
MongoDB support => enabled
MongoDB extension version => 1.4.4
MongoDB extension stability => stable
libbson bundled version => 1.9.4
libmongoc bundled version => 1.9.4
libmongoc SSL => disabled
libmongoc crypto => disabled
libmongoc SASL => disabled
libmongoc compression => enabled
libmongoc compression snappy => disabled
libmongoc compression zlib => enabled
```

How can I enable it?

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this error in PHP7 execute following command as super user:

1. Install required dependencies:

> yum install git php-devel make gcc openssl-devel

2. Clone, compile and build Mongo PHP Driver from source:

> git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git
>
> cd mongo-php-driver/
>
> git submodule update --init
>
> phpize
>
> ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
>   --with-mongodb-ssl=openssl
>
> make
>
> cp ./modules/mongodb.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/

3. Add mongodb.so to php.ini if not already there.

> "extension=mongodb.so"

4. Restart the webserver to reflect the changes:

> systemctl restart httpd.service

Answer (score 1):

You can remove mongodb extension first:

```
pecl uninstall mongodb
```

Install openssl

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel
```

Reinstall MongoDB extension again

```
pecl install mongodb
```