# Alpine 3.8 Docker image: Enabling SSL on libmongoc

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, alpine-linux

I am currently building a base image for my project. The project is using mongodb. I've successfully created the image but an error shows up when I try to call the endpoint which is related with SSL on libmongoc:

```
The SCRAM_SHA_256 authentication mechanism requires libmongoc built with ENABLE_SSL
```

Below are the some notable stuffs about my docker image:

- alpine 3.8
- php 7.2
- nginx
- lumen-framework 5.6.*

Below are the current implementation which has the problem, your suggestions are appreciated:

```
FROM alpine:3.8

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk --no-cache add composer curl gcc git make musl-dev nginx \
    openssl openssl-dev php7 php7-ctype php7-curl php7-dev \
    php7-dom php7-fileinfo php7-fpm php7-gd php7-iconv \
    php7-imagick php7-intl php7-json php7-mbstring php7-mysqli \
    php7-opcache php7-openssl php7-pdo php7-pdo_mysql php7-pear \
    php7-redis php7-simplexml php7-tokenizer php7-xdebug \
    php7-xmlreader php7-xmlwriter php7-zip php7-zlib supervisor tzdata
RUN pecl install mongodb \
    && pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php7/php.ini \
    && echo "extension=mongodb.so" > /etc/php7/conf.d/20_mongodb.ini
```

Aside from above Dockerfile, I also tried to manually build the mongo-php-driver based on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763821/how-can-i-enable-libmongoc-ssl-in-php-7-for-mongodb-connection) , but it doesn't help. Both options still show me that SSL is disabled when I check with `php -i | grep mongo`. Do tell me if I need to include another information.

Comment: Can you please extract and provide a [mcve]? Also, search for that error message online. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The original post was over a year ago.  But I also was trumped by this error:
`The SCRAM_SHA_256 authentication mechanism requires libmongoc built with ENABLE_SSL`.

The solutions below assume that you have a docker-compose configuration for mongodb.

My solution was to first stop and remove the container that is implementing mongoDB ... call that container `workspace`:

#### Stack:

- latest alpine
- nginx
- php7.3,
- Laravel 8.x

#### Dockerfile work for creation of mongodb extension

```yaml
RUN apk add redis gnupg openrc openssl libbsd==0.9.1-r1 && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN apk update && apk upgrade &&\
    apk add --no-cache php7-pear php7-dev php7-openssl gcc musl-dev make &&\
    apk add curl-dev openssl openssl-dev &&\
    pecl channel-update pecl.php.net &&\
    pecl install mongodb &&\
    pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php7/php.ini

RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /etc/php7/php.ini &&\
    php --ri mongodb
```

#### Build the container

```yaml
docker-compose stop workspace && docker-compose rm -f workspace && docker-compose build --no-cache workspace
```

#### Bashing into the container: `docker-compose exec workspace bash`

> verify that MongoDB is in fact existing as a php module:

```
bash-5.0# php -m | grep mongodb
mongodb
```

#### Verify SSL Enabled on libmongoc

```
enter command: php --ri mongodb
```

##### Response is:

```
bash-5.0# php --ri mongodb

mongodb <<<<<< Response means mongo is enabled.  See more below.

MongoDB support => enabled
MongoDB extension version => 1.12.0
MongoDB extension stability => stable
libbson bundled version => 1.20.0
libmongoc bundled version => 1.20.0
libmongoc SSL => enabled <<<< SSL Enabled fixes the problem.
libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL
libmongoc crypto => enabled
libmongoc crypto library => libcrypto
libmongoc crypto system profile => disabled
libmongoc SASL => disabled
libmongoc ICU => disabled
libmongoc compression => enabled
libmongoc compression snappy => disabled
libmongoc compression zlib => enabled
libmongoc compression zstd => disabled
libmongocrypt bundled version => 1.3.0
libmongocrypt crypto => enabled
libmongocrypt crypto library => libcrypto

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
mongodb.mock_service_id => Off => Off
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands in the following order-

```
wget https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases/download/1.18.0/mongo-c-driver-1.18.0.tar.gz
tar xzf mongo-c-driver-1.18.0.tar.gz
cd mongo-c-driver-1.18.0
mkdir cmake-build
cd cmake-build
cmake ..
```

Then make sure all the downloaded modules were placed in the extension directory which is detailed in the *php.ini's* `phpinfo()`

Then add `extension=“libmongoc.so”` and `#extension=“mongodb.so”` to *php.ini*.

Then finally remember to restart the machine or docker container in your instance.